# Does the memory used by tmpfs can be recycled just like page cache?

Tags: linux, tmpfs

I am using **tmpfs** with `/tmp` directory. However, when i add files, the output of the `free -h` shows that the `cached` column value will increase as well.

However, i am wondering that **page cache** usage info is also added into `cached`. Does the memory used by files in `/tmp` directory can be recycled when we lack of memory just like what we do for **page cache**.

Comment: tmpfs is in the pagecache and can be swapped to disk. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt

Comment: @iporsircer  if i close the swap, then can tmpfs memory be recycled when the machine is less of memory.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [kernel tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt):

> size:      The limit of allocated bytes for this tmpfs instance. The 
>              default is half of your physical RAM without swap. If you
>              oversize your tmpfs instances the machine will deadlock
>              since the OOM handler will not be able to free that memory.

It is clearly said that the tmpfs memory can not be recycled.